# Laravel : Unique validation with different fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a table `states` and fields are `id,country_id,state_code,state_name`.Now I want to validate that same country doesn't have a same `state_code` and same `state_name` in a table.

I tried but it's not working.

In my Controller :

```
    $validator = State::validator($request->all(), $id); 
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withErrors($validator->getMessageBag())
            ->withInput($request->all());
    }
```

Here is my validation function in model :

```
protected function validator(array $data, $id)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'country_id'               => 'required',
        'state_code'               => 'required',
        'state_name'               => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

How can I solved this without custom validation ?

Comment: For a little clarification; do you need a unique validation rule that checks the uniqueness of a combination of `state_code` and `state_name`? I would think that `state_code` would be unique enough on its own, and you shouldn't have to worry about `state_name`.

Comment: country `Romania`,state `Gorj` has same code `GJ` for  `Gujarat` state

Comment: Ah, I see; good example. In that case, consider something like a `slug` column, which is a lower-cased, `-` separated string of "unique" parts, like `ro-gj-gorj` and `ro-gj-gurarat`; constructed from `country_code`, `state_code`, `state_name`, and check uniqueness of that.

Comment: sure ll try and let u know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your validation rules are only checking if these fields are present in the request. There is no validation happening for a value exists in database. First of all, you might wanna go through the documentation for the [`rule_exists`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-exists). Secondly, you may have to update the query for this rule as per the documentation

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::exists('staff')->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('account_id', 1);
        }),
    ],
]);
```

Here you can pass additional query parameters.

Comment: of-course i know that it is checking only the required field, As i don't want to confuse with my code.

Comment: so did you try `rule_exists` with your custom query?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a custom validation for that one, laravel has a unique column validation

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'country_id' => 'required',
    'state_code' => 'required|unique:states,state_name',
    'state_name' => 'required|unique:states,state_code',
]);
```

This way you know for sure that column values in `state_code` will be unique compare to `state_name` for more check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-unique)